# How to set focus on input control of last row second column of html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, focus

I have to set focus on the last row second column while clicking add new row button.

[image]

row append code:

```
$("#tblDetItems").append('<tr><td align="right">' + sl_no + '</td><td td style="width: 200px; height: 13px;"><input type="text"  id="txtCode" value="" style="width: 190px; height: 13px;" /></td><td>' + "" + '</td><td>' + "" + '</td><td align="right" style="width: 100px; height: 13px;"><input type="text"  id="txtStdRate" value="0.00" style="width: 100px; height: 13px;" /></td><td align="right" style="width: 100px; height: 13px;"><input type="text"  id="txtLbrCharge" value="0.00" style="width: 100px; height: 13px;" /></td><td align="right" style="width: 100px; height: 13px;"><input type="text"  id="txtRcvryCost" value"0.00" style="width: 100px; height: 13px;" /></td><td style="width:80px; height: 18px;"><select id="cmbUseId_tbl"  style="width: 80px; height: 18px;"><option value="Y" selected="selected">Yes</option><option value="N">No</option></select></td></tr>');
```

Comment: It should be noted that element IDs are required to be unique. Your append code creates `<input>` elements with the same `id` attribute on each additional row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give any selector to every textbox you create i.e. class name.

```
<input type="text" class="fooClass" value="" />
```

then use jQuery last keyword to make it focus after generating last row.

```
$( ".fooClass:last" ).focus();
```